# is it possible to query number of active block number in Cuda Device?

Tags: cuda

I want to learn number of blocks configured to launch in the device kernel for runtime. Is there any function or way to do it ?

Comment: Can you provide additional information on how you will use this information so we can provider better feedback? The various CUDA profilers expose the PM counter active_warps per SM. This can be used to estimate average blocks per SM. Since this information is per SM there is the possibility at run time querying the per SM value but not the device value. If you want the device value at run time one option would be to maintain a software counter using atomics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find exact number with one line but `gridDim.x gridDim.y ...` gives what I want and you might get the number by these values if you know what dimensional kernel you are working at.

Comment: Do you want to find out number of active blocks or block configured to launch?

Comment: I don't get what is wrong about your suggested method, i.e. `gridDim.x*gridDim.y*gridDim.z*blockDim.x*blockDim.y*blockDim.z`. Why it shouldn't work?