# How to count number of executed thread for whole the CUDA kernel execution?

Tags: cuda

I want to count the number of thread execution gradually for whole the kernel execution. Is there an native counter for this or is there any other method to do that? I know keeping a global variable and increment by each thread would not work since a variable in global memory does not guarantees the synchronized access by the threads.

Comment: You mean the number of threads that a kernel uses? I think that's compile-time parameter...

Comment: What do you mean by "number of thread execution"?

Comment: For the whole kernel execution how any thread are executed. For example if 5 threads are active with 2 blocks and each block is executed twice than the expected number is 20. Got It?

Comment: You can keep a global counter of the number of active threads, as long as you update it via atomic operations.

Comment: @tera if possible can you give an example.

Comment: I can't give an example because it is unclear to me what exactly you want to know (and why you think you want to know it). Please give some more details.

Comment: I would like to convert an iterative solution into kernel version. Since I want to compare execution time for both, I want to compare number of thread execution with the number of iteration as each thread execution doing one iteration work. Is it clear ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's still not clear to me. Unless you want to know the total number of threads executed which is the _blocksize_ times the _number of blocks_ executed, which are the first two parameters between <<< >>> in your kernel launch.

Comment: How is your question different from [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881309/is-it-possible-to-query-number-of-active-block-number-in-cuda-device/15881726) you already asked a while ago and gave the trivial answer yourself?

Comment: @tera , it is totally different, answer of the former question was blockDim*gridDim. If you would look at answer discussion of that question you recognize the difference or you still not get the question right. I want to know how many times there were a thread activity at the kernel not number of active threads.

Comment: Indeed I still don't understand what you are asking for. What do you mean by "thread activity"?

Comment: execution of the thread. As you know when some threads are waiting for execution some warps of threads are executed so these executed ones are active and I call each of those executions of each thread as activity. Clear?

Comment: I would say every thread you configure in the kernel launch configuration would be active at some point in time. So I do not see a point in counting what you say.  Otherwise I do not get it either. In any case you said you wanted to compare kernel execution time which can be measured using the API. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/5801890/2064818

Comment: You could keep a variable in global memory and have each thread increment it using an [atomic function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions).  That would guarantee synchronized access from all threads.  Something like `atomicAdd(global_ptr, 1);` at the beginning of the kernel code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
__global__ void mykernel(int *current_thread_count, ...){
  atomicAdd(current_thread_count, 1);
  // the rest of your kernel code
  }


int main() {
  int tally, *dev_tally;
  cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_tally, sizeof(int));
  tally = 0;
  cudaMemcpy(dev_tally, &tally, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  ....
  // set up block and grid dimensions, etc.
  dim3 grid(...);
  dim3 block(...)

  mykernel<<<grid, block>>>(dev_tally, ...);
  cudaMemcpy(&tally, dev_tally, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
  printf("total number of threads that executed was: %d\n", tally);
  ....

  return 0;
  }
```

You can read more about atomic functions [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions)

Part of the reason for the confusion expressed by many in the comments, is that when `mykernel` is complete (assuming it ran successfully) everyone expects `tally` to end up with a value equal to `grid.x*grid.y*grid.z*block.x*block.y*block.z`

Comment: @GregSmith has provided a better answer.

Answer (score 8):

There are numerous ways to measure thread level execution efficiency. This answer provides a list of different collection mechanisms. Robert Crovella's answer provides a manual instrumentation method that allows for accurately collection of information. A similar technique can be used to collect divergence information in the kernel.

**Number of Threads Launched for Execution (static)**

gridDim.x * gridDim.y * gridDim.z * blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z

**Number of Threads Launched**

gridDim.x * gridDim.y * gridDim.z * ROUNDUP((blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z), WARP_SIZE)

This number includes threads that are inactive for the life time of the warp.

This can be collected using the PM counter threads_launched.

**Warp Instructions Executed**

The counter inst_executed counts the number of warp instructions executed/retired.

**Warp Instructions Issued**

The counter inst_issued counts the number of instructions issued. inst_issued >= inst_executed. Some instructions will be issued multiple times per instruction executed in order to handle dispatch to narrow execution units or in order to handle address divergence in shared memory and L1 operations.

**Thread Instructions Executed**

The counter thread_inst_executed counts the number of thread instructions executed. The metrics avg_threads_executed_per_instruction can be derived using thread_inst_executed / inst_executed. The maximum value for this counter is WARP_SIZE.

**Not Predicated Off Threads Instructions Executed**

Compute capability 2.0 and above devices use instruction predication to disable write-back for threads in a warp as a performance optimization for short sequences of divergent instructions.

The counter not_predicated_off_thread_inst_executed counts the number of instructions executed by all threads. This counter is only available on compute capability 3.0 and above devices.

not_predicated_off_thread_inst_executed <= thread_inst_executed <= WARP_SIZE * inst_executed

This relationship will be off slightly on some chips due to small bugs in thread_inst_executed and not_predicated_off_thread_inst_executed counters.

**Profilers**

Nsight Visual Studio Edition 2.x support collecting the aforementioned counters.

Nsight VSE 3.0 supports a new Instruction Count experiment that can collect per SASS instruction statistics and show the data in table form or next to high level source, PTX, or SASS code. The information is rolled up from SASS to high level source. The quality of the roll up depends on the ability of the compiler to output high quality symbol information. It is recommended that you always look at both source and SASS at the same time. This experiment can collect the following per instruction statistics:

a. inst_executed
b. thread_inst_executed (or active mask)
c. not_predicated_off_thread_inst_executed (active predicate mask)
d. histogram of active_mask
e. histogram of predicate_mask

Visual Profiler 5.0 can accurately collect the aforementioned SM counters. nvprof can collect and show the per SM details. Visual Profiler 5.x does not support collection of per instruction statistics available in Nsight VSE 3.0. Older versions of the Visual Profiler and CUDA command line profiler can collect many of the aforementioned counters but the results may not be as accurate as the 5.0 and above version of the tools.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. I sometimes wonder why the CUDA profilers don't provide the number off cycles where no warp was runnable at all (i.e. "`instructions issued0`" in analogy to `instructions issued1` and `instructions issued2`) which is one of the most interesting events for optimization and might be what Erogol is after. `sm_efficiency` contains similar information, but since it seems to be derived from events sampled in different runs can easily be off by 10% or so.

Comment: @tera I'll add a RFE for the counter in CUPTI/nvprof/VisualProfiler.  Nsight VSE supports the counter in the "PM Counters - Fermi/Kepler" raw counter experiment. The % of cycles (Instruction Isssued 0 / Active Cycles) is also shown in the Issue Efficiency experiment pie chart.

Comment: Thank you Greg! Finally a reason to use Windows. ;) Big thanks for the RFE to bring it to the unixoides as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to calculate the number of threads in a specific path branch. for ex for an histogram, it would be nice to have the following:

PS: Histogram is about counting the pixels for each color.

`for (i=0; i<256; i++)    // 256 colors, 1 pixel = 1 thread
   if (threadidx.x == i)
   Histogramme[i] = CUDA_NbActiveThreadsInBranch() // Threads having i as color`